# How to fetch data from Promise in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access the data returned as a response after executing promise. The response returned in the form of json is a hashmap. I need to access the keys and values of the same.The different keys and their corresponding values need to be displayed in each of the dialog box:-

I have already tried to access the data in the below fashion:-

component.ts :

```js
openDialog(emaildialog){
   this.emailservice.getByEmailType(this.choice).then((emails: any) => {
      this.etext = emails.responsive;
      console.log(emails.responsive);
      let ref = this.dialog.open(emaildialog, {    
         data: emails.responsive,
         width: "600px",
         height: "600px",
      });
   });
}
```

service.ts:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getByEmailType(id:String) {
   return this.http.get<Email>(this.baseUrl+'/'+id).toPromise();
}
```

In the backend as Srpingboot the api returns the following data:

```java
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(Collections.singletonMap("responsive",hmap), HttpStatus.OK);
```

The returned json looks as follows:

```
{
   "responsive": {
      "email3": "hello to email3",
      "email2": "hello to email2",
      "email1": "hello to email1",
      "email5": "hello to email5",
      "email4": "hello to email4"
   }
}
```

I need to access each of the email types as keys and the corresponding values. I need to display them in separate dialog box for each of the email type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
Object.keys(emails.responsive).forEach(e => {
      let ref = this.dialog.open(emaildialog, {    
         data: emails.responsive[e],
         width: "600px",
         height: "600px",
      });
});
```